# Problema con MergeSort

Tags: java, algoritmos

Estoy implementando el algoritmo de mergeSort genérico de tal manera que pueda usarlo con cualquier elemento que sea comparable pero al hacer las pruebas con los test no me salen bien ordenados y no se que puedo tener mal, ya que lo he revisado varías veces y no veo nada que pueda impedir que no ordene correctamente. les estaría agradecidos si le echan un vistazo. Gracias de antemano!

```
public class ordenacio<T> {

   public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void mergeSort(T[] v){
       mergeSort(v,0,v.length - 1); //metode llançadera
   }


   private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void mergeSort(T[] v, int ini, int fi) {

       if(ini - fi >= 1) {
           int meitat = (ini + fi) / 2; //problemes de tamany relatiu no tamany fixe
           mergeSort(v,ini,meitat);
           mergeSort(v,meitat + 1, fi);
           merge(v,ini,meitat,fi);
       }
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   private static <T extends Comparable<T>>  void merge(T[] v, int ini, int meitat, int fi) {
       int i = ini;
       int j = meitat + 1;
       int k = 0;

       T[] aux = (T[]) new Comparable[(fi - ini + 1)]; //comparable pq T es generic i volem tipus generics d'altra banda fi - ini + 1 pq son tamanys relatius

       while(i <= meitat && j <= fi) { //en el moment que uno dels dos arribe al final acabarà.
           if(v[i].compareTo(v[j]) < 0){ // v[i] < v[j]
               aux[k] = v[i];
               i++;
           } else {
               aux[k] = v[j];
               j++;
           }

           k++; //si o si en qualsevol dels dos casos k ha de avançar 
       }

       while(i <= meitat) { //per si la part de meitat + 1 ha arribat al final i la part de ini fins a meitat encara no ha acabat i necessitem copiar els elemetns que queden en la primera part
           aux[k] = v[i];
           k++;
           i++;
       }

       while(j <= fi) { //el mateix que en el bucle anterior pero al reves
           aux[k] = v[j];
           k++;
           j++;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu implementación de `mergeSort`, en el primer condicional verifica si la diferencia entre `ini` y `fi` es mayor o igual que 1 y debería ser si `ini` es mayor o igual que `fi`.

El condicional actual siempre evalúa a `false`, ya que `ini - fi` siempre será negativo.

Cambia esta línea:

```
if(ini - fi >= 1) {
```

por esta:

```
if (ini >= fi) {
```

Además, para que el algoritmo `mergeSort` realmente ordene los elementos del array `v`, debes copiar los elementos del array auxiliar `aux` de vuelta al array original `v` después de que todos los elementos hayan sido ordenados en el array auxiliar. Para hacer esto, agrega el siguiente bucle al final de la función `merge`:

```
for (int l = 0; l < k; l++) {
    v[ini + l] = aux[l];
}
```